# Display Emotion Data Properly Using Json

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, string-formatting, stringify

I'm working on an emotion reader. Users press a button and the screen starts displaying emotional data.

My problem is since it is using JSON's `stringify`, it displays the data in one straight line:

```
{ "joy":50, "sadness":0, "anger:0", "surprise": 0, "fear": 0, "contempt": 0, "disgust": 0}
```

I want to remove the curly braces. I also want to find a way to style the text `joy`, perhaps by adding bold or colors to the text but I'm not familiar with modifying JSON data.

```
detector.addEventListener("onImageResultsSuccess", function(faces, image, timestamp) {
    $('#results').html("");
    if (faces.length > 0) {      
        log('#results', 
            "<b>Emotions: </b>" + JSON.stringify(faces[0].emotions, function(key, val){
             return val.toFixed ? Number(val.toFixed(0)) : val;
            })
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Your `faces` object and `faces[0].emotions` object aren't JSON (it doesn't become JSON until you serialise, i.e., stringify it). Anyway, some tutorials on [working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) might be a good place to start.